# Getting the Max date/end date in Oracle query

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

HI all, I am new to Oracle. My table structure is as follows. I need to find the end date/effective to date for each line. If no new records are there then end date should be **SYSDATE**. What will be the simple select query for this?

> Please note effective to date should be next effective from date -1

Thanks in advance.

[image]

My sample output should be like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is per item_code, item_cost_gp. You can use analytical functions for this:

```
SELECT item_code, ...
     , coalesce(lead(eff_frm_date) 
                over (partition by item_code, item_cost_gp
                      order by eff_frm_date) - 1
               , SYSDATE) as eff_to_date
FROM ...
```

untested since you did not provide any ddl to test with

Comment: you should probably move the accept to @balazs-papp 's answer. The idea is similar, but he added more info that is of use for anyone looking at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

[LEAD](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LEAD.html)

Sample data:

```
with data as
(
  select 1010 as item_code, 'UAECOSTGP' as item_cost_gp, 5 as item_cost, 'AVK' as created_by, date'2018-09-12' as eff_frm_date from dual union all
  select 1010 as item_code, 'UAECOSTGP' as item_cost_gp, 5.3 as item_cost, 'AVK' as created_by, date'2019-03-29' as eff_frm_date from dual union all
  select 1010 as item_code, 'UAECOSTGP' as item_cost_gp, 5.8 as item_cost, 'AVK' as created_by, date'2019-06-06' as eff_frm_date from dual union all
  select 1010 as item_code, 'QARCOSTGP' as item_cost_gp, 3 as item_cost, 'AVK' as created_by, date'2019-03-29' as eff_frm_date from dual
)
select * from data;

 ITEM_CODE ITEM_COST  ITEM_COST CRE EFF_FRM_DA
---------- --------- ---------- --- ----------
      1010 UAECOSTGP          5 AVK 2018-09-12
      1010 UAECOSTGP        5.3 AVK 2019-03-29
      1010 UAECOSTGP        5.8 AVK 2019-06-06
      1010 QARCOSTGP          3 AVK 2019-03-29
```

Desired output:

```
with data as
(
  select 1010 as item_code, 'UAECOSTGP' as item_cost_gp, 5 as item_cost, 'AVK' as created_by, date'2018-09-12' as eff_frm_date from dual union all
  select 1010 as item_code, 'UAECOSTGP' as item_cost_gp, 5.3 as item_cost, 'AVK' as created_by, date'2019-03-29' as eff_frm_date from dual union all
  select 1010 as item_code, 'UAECOSTGP' as item_cost_gp, 5.8 as item_cost, 'AVK' as created_by, date'2019-06-06' as eff_frm_date from dual union all
  select 1010 as item_code, 'QARCOSTGP' as item_cost_gp, 3 as item_cost, 'AVK' as created_by, date'2019-03-29' as eff_frm_date from dual
)
select
  item_code, item_cost_gp, item_cost, created_by, eff_frm_date, 
  lead(eff_frm_date, 1, sysdate + 1) over (partition by item_code, item_cost_gp order by  eff_frm_date) -1 as eff_to_date
from data
order by 1, 2 desc, 5;

 ITEM_CODE ITEM_COST  ITEM_COST CRE EFF_FRM_DA EFF_TO_DAT
---------- --------- ---------- --- ---------- ----------
      1010 UAECOSTGP          5 AVK 2018-09-12 2019-03-28
      1010 UAECOSTGP        5.3 AVK 2019-03-29 2019-06-05
      1010 UAECOSTGP        5.8 AVK 2019-06-06 2019-07-14
      1010 QARCOSTGP          3 AVK 2019-03-29 2019-07-14
```